# Associations issue with Thinking Sphinx plugin for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have many **sphinx_scopes** in my application's models, but one of
them doesn't work, I think it's because the odd way Sphinx store the
associated values.

As an example I will show some key pieces of my Product class model,
product.rb:

```
...
belongs_to :partner
# And partner belongs to city
...
define_index do
   ...
   has partner.city(:state_name), :as => :state, :type => :string
   #has partner.city.state_name, :as => :state, :type => :string
   ...
end
...
sphinx_scope(:by_state) { | name | {
   :with => { :state => name }
 } }
```

Then I try in console:

```
Product.by_state('whatever_i_put_here_throws_same_resultset')
```

I guess sphinx is not storing the string properly, any ideas? Thanks a
lot!

Comment: *I tried with :conditions instead of :with, with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked the authors: http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/22fe3c7aa6ef4567

Found the problem here: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#string_filters

Answer (score 0):

You defined your scope as `:by_state` but you're trying to call `Product.by_city`. Is there another scope defined that we're not seeing here?